# Decode umlauts with a python sql-query through ssh-connection

Tags: python, decode

I'm trying to establish a ssh connection to mysql-database via python. I get the data i request but with encoded umlauts..

Example: instead of `"Jörg"` I receive something like `"J\xf6rg"`.

So the question is, how can I put some additional code in the actual query in order to make everything work right.

In the terminal everything works fine as soon as I add `--default-character-set-utf8` but I don't know how to really do this in python. Adding a `charset=utf8` in the pymsql connector didnt help..

**Here is my code:**

```py
with SSHTunnelForwarder(

        '231.323.2.12.',

        ssh_username="myname",

        ssh_password="mypw",

        remote_bind_address=("127.0.0.1", 3306)) as tunnel:

        port = tunnel.local_bind_port

        db_connection = pymysql.connect(host="127.0.01", 
                        port=port, db="kalender",user="oktay" 
                        password="mypw")

        cursor = db_connection.cursor()

        query =  '''SELECT 
                          CONCAT("[",
                            GROUP_CONCAT(
                              CONCAT("{BID:'",BID,"'"),
                                                
                              CONCAT("Benutzer:'",Benutzer,"'"),
                                                
                              CONCAT(",Vorname:'",Vorname,"'}")
                                        )
                                ,"]") 
                     AS json FROM termincal_ben;
                  '''
                
  #my last attempt to set the charset to utf8..             
               
 cursor.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;') 

 cursor.execute(query)

 result = cursor.fetchall()
                
  print(result)
              
                
        
 db_connection.close()
```

Comment: Hard to tell without being able to see your code.

Comment: Sorry, now i did..

Comment: You just proved there's nothing to decode - this page is UTF8 just like most (if not all) web pages. Unicode isn't some kind of escape sequence. That's why you were able to type `Jörg` and I can type `Αυτό Εδώ`. Most likely, what you see is how your debugger or console displays the non-US-ASCII letters. Python 3 strings are Unicode but printing to the console may display strings as binary "strings" with unprintable characters replaced by escape sequences

Comment: Unless the application tried to "fix" Unicode and generated those escape sequences. In that case the "encoding" code should be removed

Comment: What does `print(len(result))` return? I suspect it doesn't count any escape sequences because they aren't there

Comment: len(result) is in this case the numbers of rows which are printed out. This returns 1.